# IA32 Assembly clarification

Tags: assembly, x86, att

I am working on an assignment that requires debugging AT&T assembly. I am having trouble with the following two lines, and just wanted to ask for a little clarification.

```
add    -0x8(%esi,%ebx,4),%eax
cmp    %eax,-0x4(%esi,%ebx,4)
```

I know that `%esi` holds the value input by the user, and both `%eax` and `%ebx` are equal to 2.

For the first line, I am interpreting this as "`-8 + %esi + (%ebx*4) + %eax`". Since I know `%ebx` is 2, this evaluates to  `%esi + %eax`. So essentially, the add line just adds 2 to the input value.

The second line I know is comparing `%eax` to `-0x4(%esi,%ebx,4)`. At this point `%eax` equals `%esi + 2`, and following the previous logic the right side value equals `-4 + %esi + (%ebx*4)` which would evaluate to `%esi + 4` since `%ebx` is still equal to 2.

If I am correct, the that means the second line is comparing `%esi + 2` to `%esi + 4` which can never be true for any input value. Yet, it has to be true as per the assignment. Where am I going wrong in my translation?

Comment: Paste more code. There is probably a loop which updates esi or ebx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those are memory operands.

```
add    -0x8(%esi,%ebx,4),%eax
```

Adds the value stored at address `esi + ebx*4 - 8` to `eax`.

```
cmp    %eax,-0x4(%esi,%ebx,4)
```

Compares the value stored at address `esi + ebx*4 - 4` with `eax`.